# Installing of WordPress to the branch of site

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, web

We created a website on WordPress (do it locally by Denwer - the russian example of `XAMPP`). It's time to test and to rearrange it to the branch of site. For example, `http://site.ru/test/`. I.e. when I am handling to this address, our site should open by WordPress, but not old pattern `http://site.ru` (there are only `html/css` code). I threw in a folder "test" by the FTP all files of WordPress, made the import of the database, replacing her line, which was listed a local address of the site (for example, `primer/` to `http: //site.ru/test/`. The site is installed. The home page works without bugs, but when you're trying to go to any page of the site WP, an error `404` is occured: "Not Found. The requested URL `/index.php` was not found on this server." Question: Is it possible in any way to fix this? If so, how? Thank you and sorry for my english

Comment: A fix is always possible. What is not possible, is to solve your problems without you showing us some code, because your link references can be broken, the routers can be misplaced and a lot of other things can be going on but, without any code, we are left to guess.

Comment: And by "code" I mean **relevant** code, please don't dump your entire project here.

Comment: Can you tell me on your server on `options_name` table what are the values of site_url and blog_url ?

Comment: the code of the database? or I understood you wrong?

Comment: http://s30.postimg.org/m8bmwm60h/stackoverflow.png screen of table 'options_name' of my datebase

Comment: I solved! Problem was being in file .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you properly, you can open your .sql file with Dreamweaver or a similar program, replace your current url with the new url and be on your way. You also have to make sure that your Wordpress URL and Site URL also get changed in the mix as well. These are in the options section of your Wordpress database.

Comment: This website is also very helpful: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/